# making logback filename in TimeBasedRollingPolicy use leading 0s for %i

Tags: logback

Is there any way to make logback create TimeBasedRollingPolicy file names that use leading 0s for %i. Here's an excerpt from the logback.xml file

```
...
<rollingPolicy class="ch.quos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>logs/foo_%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
     ...
</rollingPolicy>
...
```

This creates files named like this foo_20130501-0.log, foo_20130501-1.log, ... foo_20130501-9.log, foo_20130501-10.log, ...

Instead, I would like the files named like this: foo_20130501-000.log, foo_20130501-001.log, ... foo_20130501-009.log, foo_20130501-010.log, ...

Answer (score 1):

No, as of 2013-05-01, this is not possible with logback version 1.0.12 or earlier. Please create a [jira issue](http://jira.qos.ch) requesting this feature.

Comment: Thank you Ceki: please see LOGBACK-854